# Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery-2.1.4.min

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm newbie in the world of JavaScript programming.

I'm trying to get the plugin work on WordPress, but I'm getting this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoBlocks is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (?p=40:408)
    at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Is this the plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/photoblocks-grid-gallery ?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks so much, Don't know how I missed that.. 
yeah I'll transfer my question to that forum.. 

Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in this problem. Firstly, two jQuery is being added in your file

Also, you need to change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     'enter code here'
});
```

to

```
(function(){
   'enter code here'
})(jQuery);
```